# .NET MAUI app doesn't start in Android emulator

Tags: c#, android-emulator, .net-6.0, .net-maui

I'm new to MAUI so I followed the instructions on [Microsoft's Build Your First App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?tabs=vswin&pivots=devices-android#:%7E:text=In%20this%20tutorial%2C%20you%27ll%20create%20your%20first%20.NET,have%20.NET%207%20Preview%20installed.%20...%20More%20items) page. I ran the Android emulator and everything worked fine.

I then followed [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/flashlight?tabs=android) to build a flashlight app, but when I ran it, the emulator started fine, but the app never loaded.

In the output window in Visual Studio, I saw this:

```
[mono] debugger-agent: Unable to connect to 10.0.2.2:54762
```

I created a brand new .NET MAUI app, made no changes and ran that, same result.

I followed the deployment issues section on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/troubleshooting) to no avail.

Also, when I ran `sdkmanager --update`, I got the following output:

```
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...
Updating:
platform-tools
emulator
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
[===                                    ] 10% Installing Android Emulator
```

where it's saying it failed to read/install the properties file.

I also tried Razwill-1930's answer on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382625/xamarin-forms-debugger-agent-unable-to-connect.html), again, to no avail.

I'm running .NET 6 in Visual Studio 17.3.5 on Windows 11 Pro.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

I downloaded another emulator and that one works fine, which for my purposes, I'm OK with not being able to use the Pixel 6 emulator that gets installed with the .NET MAUI workload in VS. How can I get it going?

Comment: You can try creating a new project without the flashlight and running to see if you have the same problem. Regarding the warning about updating the SDK, you can check if you are running the compiler as administrator.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Thanks, yes, I tried that, same result. I've come across a few pages mentioning this problem, but it was regarding previous version of Visual Studio and they'd been marked as closed, bug fixed.

Comment: I am guessing there was an issue with your Emulator Creation which might be causing this issue, can you try creating a new Emulator with the latest possible Android SDK image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up deleting the emulator (Pixel 5 - API 31) and then reinstalling it.
That worked.
Not sure why that worked, the Android Device Manager didn't re-download the files.
Hey, banging the TV sometimes works too.

Comment: Like i said the issue seemed to be with the emulator creation, do you want me to as it as an answer, Don't let that 100 reps go to waste :P

Comment: Sure, close enough.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your emulator, I would highly recommend you recreate the emulator. Points to remember when doing so:

- Make sure you have the latest version of the API version's Image
- Select Arm64 as your processor (has lesser lag).
- Hardware-based GUI has better performance.

Just FYI Assigning too much RAM won't make it faster

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I disabled both mobile data and Wi-Fi on my Pixel 5 emulator. After re-enabling them, the problem was resolved, and the connection was established successfully.

The error message "[mono] debugger-agent: Unable to connect to 10.0.2.2:54762" indicates that the debugger agent is unable to establish a connection to the specified host. In this case, it is attempting to connect to the IP address 10.0.2.2 on port 54762.

The IP address 10.0.2.2 is commonly used in Android emulators to refer to the host machine. The port 54762 is typically used for communication between the emulator and the debugger agent.

**To resolve this issue, make sure that both mobile data and Wi-Fi are enabled on your emulator. By enabling these network connections, the emulator will be able to establish a connection with the debugger agent running on the host machine.**

If you continue to experience the same problem even after enabling mobile data and Wi-Fi, you may want to consider restarting the emulator or trying a different emulator to determine if the issue is specific to the used emulator or if it persists across different emulator configurations.